# Using custom css for login page

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot for making a website. I'd like to use my own login page and style it using CSS. However, the CSS does not get linked to the HTML page (powered by thymleaf) property.

Base on the defined CSS, I expect to get a red background colour for the login page, but this does not happen. Moreover, when the login proceed successfully, instead of get redirected to the index.html, it shows me style.css

I really appreciate if someone could help me to figure out how to link the css file properly to the html file

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerManager {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/",""} )
    public String homePage(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigManager extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

login.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Please Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Login</legend>
                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Invalid username and password.
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
                </div>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

template/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Please Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<p th:text="Hello World">Greeting</p>
</body>
</html>
```

static/css/style.css

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Before login:
[image]

After login:

[image]

When I click on the go back (<--) button the style get applied:
[image]

Debugger When I want to login:
[image]

Debugger after login:
[image]

Debugger after clicking on the go back button:

[image]

Comment: Maybe because your css file is called `style.css` but you include `login.css` in your `login.html`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was my typo in the question and I edited that. The erroneous behaviour was not because of that.

Comment: Did you include the line `spring.resources.add-mappings=true` in your `application.properties` file?

Comment: Yes, I did include that.

Comment: Can you show us the generated html file (e.g. from your browser console) and maybe a screenshot of the file structure?

Comment: Is that good enough or you want me to post the image as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195810/discussion-between-theblackips-and-hossein).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ignore static resources as below.

#### Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigManager extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Yes, it worked thank you very much. Could you explain it as well please?

Comment: By spring security filter, All requests include ``/css/style.css`` redirect to ``login`` before login proceed finished successfully.
So you should ignore static resources to prevent this.